# Can I use a DC power pack (12dcv 3a) with an inline connector rated at 24dcv 2a?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, amperage, maximum-ratings

I have a power pack that is 12v 3a, I want to buy an inline switch so it can be turned off without having to unplug it. The following image is of the inline switch. It is rated for 24v at 2amp. If my understanding is correct, I can just multiply the V by the A and as long as it's lower than rated it's all ok.

Inline Switch: 24v x 2a = 48 watts
DC Power Pack: 12v x 3a = 36 watts
So it's ok to use.

Is this correct? Or am I mistaken and the switch shouldn't be used with this power pack?

[image: DC Inline Switch]

[image: Layout]

Comment: Simple answer is no since 3 A > 2 A, so you have violated the specification. In practice, you can somewhat trade voltage for current for a breaker but few manufacturers bothers to give their product multiple ratings. I would not heasitate one bit to use it as you intended for my own personal use. If in doubt, feel if it’s getting hot during use. Are you going to put it into production?

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly. I am plugging the power into a pretty expensive device. Would you risk $1000 on it? Sorry for bothering you further. Just want to see how big a risk I am taking.

Comment: Depends, do you have extremely long cable between the power supply and the device and very little to none input capacitance in the device? Then perhaps think twice. Also, was the DC connector pluggable and unpluggable by the user from the factory? If not and you have spliced in your breaker in series on the DC cable side, you may push the input stage to beyond what it’s tested for by the manufacturer.

Comment: I am only going to use it for myself at home. I am soldering the connection from a 12v 3a charger to the mainboard of an Xbox One Kinect to provide the additional power so I can connect it via USB 3 to my computer. Everything checks out fine for everything else (have checked on power pack and how to do it all) but I wanted to have an off switch inbetween. I just don't want to risk shorting something out and the Kinect sending additional power up through the USB cable that is not directly connected to the power and shorting out my expensive motherboard.

Comment: My main reason for doing this is because it's possible. It's not life or death for me to do it :)

Comment: Then switching action should be zero problem, but I can’t tell if you are creating a ground loop by connecting it that way. Probably not but can you sketch a simple block diagram and I will be able to tell?

Comment: Added a diagram to the question

Comment: The blue connectors are just 2.1mm male and female connectors

Comment: There is also a USB 3.0 port on the back of the Xbox One Kinect. It will run to my computer's USB port however I don't believe the device will be sending any power through that cable for any reason.

Comment: Good! I forsee no issue.

Comment: Can you please change your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, will fix it tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is no since 3 A > 2 A, so you have violated the specification.

In practice, you can somewhat trade voltage for current for a breaker but few manufacturers bothers to give their product multiple ratings. I would not heasitate one bit to use it as you intended for my own personal use. If in doubt, feel if it’s getting hot during use. To use it in mass production is another thing where you need to stay within such ratings.

Here is an example from the internet about switches in general. As the voltage goes up, the current rating drops and vice versa.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the voltage rating of the switch is higher than the supply, it is NOT a problem.  However, since the supply CAN provide 3A, if the load draws this amount, the switch will get hot and may malfunction.  But even if the switch "malfunctions," the load most likely will not be damaged.